# Idiom for getting informative errors regarding filesystem operations?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, filesystems, error-messaging

I'm using C++17 (or perhaps C++14 with the filesystem TS) to work with some files: Check their size; open them for reading or for writing etc.

Now, when doing this fails, I typically get an exception: "file not found" or "permission denied". But this doesn't tell me *which* file wasn't found nor *which* permission was denied. Thus I can't tell whether the file I tried to open is in a non-existent directory, or whether the directory exists but the file doesn't. Or - whether I have no permission to check the file, or no permission to access its containing directory.

Obviously, it's important for a user of a (console) application to know exactly what's the (filesystem-related) problem is.

Is there an idiomatic way or making these errors more specific, or should I just roll my own wrappers / pre-call validator functions to take care of this?

PS - Yes, I realize there can be race conditions in which a path passes validation, but then someone creates a file or changes permission; and that there may also be locking issues to consider. You may ignore this in your answer (or not ignore it if you want to address that too.)

Comment: Have you looked at [the `filesystem_error` exception class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/filesystem_error)?

Comment: I don't think such a detailed information is available from the operating system to begin with. When you call say [`open`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open), it may return an error code, but it won't tell which component of the path it failed to access. `filesystem` library is merely a wrapper around underlying OS functionality.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Sure it's available: You check whether the directory exists, you check the permissions, etc.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I have now, but I'm not sure what I was supposed to find in there..

Comment: @einpoklum: You wanted to know about the path in question. Well, there are functions to fetch that.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have the standard library do all this, and be much slower than the raw OS API. Besides, it would be a security concern. If you think you need this, I suspect you'd have to roll your own.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You're right that the standard library is probably not the right place for it - given that the OS doesn't provide the information. Actually, the OS kernel is where I'd expect it to be, with libraries only exposing the information, but alas, that's not the case.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Those functions will not tell me which prefix of the path is the first one that's problematic...

Comment: @einpoklum: No, but with access to the path in question, you can start searching for whatever information you like.